# Tabcontrol Navigation

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have started to develop a WPF Application. I use a `TabControl` to navigate but how can I switch the content of an `TabItem`? In the first `TabItem` I have a UserControl with a `ListView` and on double click on a row I will change the content of the `TabItem`.

TabItem:

```
<TabItem x:Name="kundenTab">
    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Kunden" FontFamily="Verdana" Style="{StaticResource TabItemText}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <z:Kunden Margin="10"/>
</TabItem>
```

ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Kunden}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Margin="10,20,10,10" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Vorname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding vorname}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Nachname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding nachname}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Telefonnummer" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding telnr}" Width="120"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Email" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding email}" Width="190"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Adresse" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding adresse}" Width="160"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is no UserControl in the sample.  What do you want to change the content to?   Define "the Tabitem"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the complexity of your implementation. If the `TabItem` content is held in a ViewModel property (with `INotifyPropertyChanged`) within each item of your `DataGrid`, then just bind that to the `TabItem` `Content` property like this:

```
<TabItem x:Name="kundenTab" Content="{Binding ElementName=myDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem.ContentProperty}">
    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Kunden" FontFamily="Verdana" Style="{StaticResource TabItemText}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <z:Kunden Margin="10"/>
</TabItem>
```

Where **ContentProperty** is the name of the INPC property in your ViewModel for the selected item.